# Where can I download the .so for OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, shared-libraries

Does anyone know if it is possible to download the latest shared library of OpenSSL [from their website](http://www.openssl.org)?

I can only find the source, so maybe they don't make it available.  I know I can build this myself from source, but I need to find a (reliable) location where I can point people to, in order for them to download themselves.

I require Linux, Solaris and Windows.

Comment: @NomNomNom - You can compile the source on all those systems with little to no effort. This does not show effort on your part.  Responding to your question why you recieved a downvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiled version will depend on the system. If you compile it on two different systems you will get two different versions of the binary.

For this reason OpenSSL only provides sources: otherwise they should build it for all the major systems and versions.

Binaries are usually distributed with the system or as an add-on package. Each Linux distribution and version has it's own version or other systems (BSD based) deliver OpenSSL as part of the OS itself.

The only binary that is provided is the one for Windows systems: http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

Comment: Don't forget the ABI. 32-bit and 64-bit Windows are different, as are 32-bit and 64-bit Linux (and which C library would you build against?) and I'd expect there to be similar differences on Solaris as well. That doesn't even begin to address the difference between x86-64, sparc64, etc.